# javascript param is a variable, how to put the value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For this code

```
            $scope.votedList.push({
                idSong: 'no'
            });
```

I need to define 'idSong' as a integer, who is a variable, so i want to do something like this :

```
$scope.myFilter = function(input, id, yourip) {
    var idSong = id;
    $scope.votedList.push({
       idSong: 'no'
    });
}
```

It's not working, 'idSong' is put as idSong, not the value of id param, so, how to get it ?

Comment: because var idSong is a variable, but { idSong... } is a property of an object. Try idSong : idSong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var entry = {};
entry[idSong] = 'no';
$scope.votedList.push(entry);
```

When using object literal notation, all keys are treated as raw strings. So instead use object assignment notation `obj[x]`.